# Solution to Laplace equation in spherical coordinates and Legendre polyomials

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, symmetry, voltage, gauss-law

I have the following problem:

> A metallic sphere of radius $R$ is placed in a region where there is an electric field $\vec{E} = E_0 \vec{e_z}$. Solve Laplace equation for the scalar potential $V(r, \theta, \phi)$.

I understand that the symmetry of the problem allows us to deduce that $V$ does not depend on $\phi$ and I have written the solution as $V(r, \theta) = R(r) \Theta(\theta)$ using the technique of separation of variables. My problem comes when I try to solve the equation for $\Theta(\theta)$. I have arrived to Legendre's differential equation:
$$
(1-x^2)y''-2xy'+l(l+1)y=0
$$
(where I have used the change of variables $x=\cos \theta$). I have looked for solutions of this equation and I understand that if $l$ is an integer then the solution is a polynomial, but when $l$ is not an integer there are valid mathematical solutions as well (infinite series). I have looked on several books that solve Laplace's equation in the context of electromagnetism and they all take the polynomials as the solutions of the equation. Is there any physical reason that enforces us to use the polynomials instead of the general series solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any physical reason that enforces us to use the polynomials instead of the general series solution?

Yes. Legendre functions where $l$ is not an integer diverge at $x=1$ or $x=-1$ or both, implying that the electric potential would have to diverge at one or both of the poles (i.e., along the positive or negative $z$-axis). Since the coordinate system is arbitrary, there's no reason why somehow the $z$ directions should be privileged, and anyway the electric potential should be finite-valued anywhere away from the source charges.

This is essentially a boundary value problem, where the "boundary condition" is that the function needs to be finite-valued at the boundaries (i.e., at $x=\pm1$ which is the same as $\theta=0$ and $\theta=\pi$).  This boundary condition forces $l$ to be an integer, because those are the only values for which the function is finite at the boundaries, and in those cases, the result is a polynomial.

In systems that are *not* azimuthally symmetric, we get associated Legendre *functions*, which are not in general polynomials, but the same result holds: $l$ must be a non-negative integer in order for the function to be finite-valued at $x=\pm1$.